# Execute HoughCircles after Inrange

Tags: c++, opencv, grayscale, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect shapes with a specific color, using openCV.
The first thing i'm trying to do, is to detect circles in an image.

I'm able to detect the circles, using houghCircles, with this function call:

```
HoughCircles(gray, c, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, gray.rows / 10, 200, 100, 0, 0);
```

Now i'm trying to detect the circles with the specific color.
I'm doing this using the inRange function, which returns a 8-bit, single-channel image.

This function is able to filter only the given color out of the image. I.e. yellow.

But when i pass the returned image in to the houghCircles function, it's returning no circles.
There are no compilation errors.

I already tried to change some of the parameters of houghCircles, but i'm not able to detect the circle.

This is an example of the image that inRange is returning:
[Grayscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb6Gt.jpg)

What parameters do i need to use, to detect the circle in that image?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

By doing some playing around with your image, I have found a set of parameters that work.

```
HoughCircles(shapes, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, shapes.rows / 4, 400, 20, 0, 0);
```

I doubt these are *ideal* parameters, and I strongly advise you to go and build your own app for changing function parameters - there are plenty of examples of simple slider-based apps in the OpenCV docs which you can use to play around with parameters until you hit upon something that works. [This one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ImgTrans/HoughCircle_Demo.cpp), for example, is a demo for Hough Circles.

Additionally, you may not be using the best tool for the job. By using contours, you should be able to detect and classify a whole bunch of different shapes, not just circles. [This tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) is very close to what you're trying to do and probably worth a read.